# Copy a callback?

Tags: c++, callback, scope

Is it possible to copy the callback of one object into another?

Right now I'm dealing with a data structure with a member like the following:

```
class Obj
{
  // some unrelated variables
  // some unrelated functions
  void (*callback)(Obj& r, void* user);
  void* callback_data;
}
```

The callback is assigned like the following:

```
o->callback = AFunctionInAnotherScope;
```

A vector of `Obj` is kept but a `clear()` has to be invoked on that vector every iteration.

The callback function is in another scope which also assigns the callback.

The current scope has no access to the callback function but I'd like to create new Obj and assign them the same callback. Is there a way to do this?

e: So far I've tried using `memcpy(&copyObj, &vectorOfObj.at(0), sizeof(Obj));` but I don't think I used that properly.

Thanks in advance.

Update: Here is what the file that creates the Obj looks like:

**Caller.cpp**

```
#include "SomeClass.h"

void Callback(Obj& r, void* dummy_data)
{
   // do things
}

int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
   for(int i = 0; i < SomeClass::vectorOfOBj.size(); ++i)
   {
      vectorOfObj.at(i).callback = Callback;
   }
}
```

Later on, in another file that doesn't have access to Caller.cpp but does have access to SomeClass.h

```
#define VAR(V,init) __typeof(init) V=(init)
#define FOR_EACH(I,C) for(VAR(I,(C).begin());I!=(C).end();I++)

void Run()
{
   FOR_EACH(o, vectorOfObjects)
   {
     Obj &b = *o;
     r->callback(b, o->callback_data);
   }

   vectorOfObjects.clear();

   // repopulate vectorOfObject, might not be the same size as before. Could be bigger
}
```

Comment: You should not use `memcpy` for class objects. You should, however, be able to make a copy using the copy constructor. The compiler will create one by default if you don't define one explicitly.

Comment: @CodyGray: To be more precise, you should not use `memcpy` (and his friends `malloc`, `realloc`, `strcpy`, `free`) on non-POD types. C structures are class objects, too, but they are POD. But indeed it's a good rule of thumb (and I would go so far to call it good practice for the average task) to not call those functions for any object, if applicable.

Comment: I left out the technical details because there's no reason to use `memcpy` on class objects at all in C++. This isn't a question about C. (whoops, you already caught that on your edit)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your callback is just a pointer, so what is wrong with simply copying it?

```
copyObj.callback = vectorOfObj.at(0).callback;
```

in your case, maybe just store the pointer before clearing the vector:

```
typedef void (*callback_t)(Obj& r, void* user);

callback_t cb = vectorOfObj.at(0).callback;
vectorOfObj.clear();

// later...
Obj o;
o.callback = cb;
```

Comment: Hmm, I assumed he wanted to create a new instance of `Obj`... Maybe I misread the question.

Comment: When the vector of Obj is cleared, it seems to lose the callback when I try this.

Comment: @noko If the above doesn't help, please post the method which clears the vector and the part where you create the new `Obj` instances.

Comment: @DanielFrey thank you for your answer, still having trouble though. I've updated my question with more info.

Comment: @noko Especially after the update of the question, my (previously updated) answer *should* help.

Comment: Hi @DanielFrey, thanks for your efforts but I tried your updated answer and callback doesn't seem to get called after calling clear() on the vector. I'm assuming that cb is getting deleted too somehow.

Comment: @noko: Where do you *call* your callback? In the dtor of `Obj`, I assume? We need more code (class `Obj`) to help, please update the question.

Comment: @DanielFrey I've updated the question with more info. `Obj` just has some unrelated functions and variables. The callback is called in a for loop of a function that has no access to Caller.cpp. I can't really change how callback is called since I'm not supposed to.

Comment: @noko: Again, my answer *should* help. If it doesn't, something else is going on that you don't show, so I can not help you, sorry. I'll be stuck in a day-long meeting now without internet, sorry.

Comment: @DanielFrey, thanks, you were right! It was something else that was causing the issue. A function to map the callback to new Obj wasn't always called!